# Why does my custom Excel function never return a value ONLY on Windows?

Tags: javascript, excel-formula, promise, office-js, office-addins

I am building an Office Excel Add-in using the web add-in framework provided by Microsoft.
This add-in also includes a custom function. Currently, the custom function is working on **Excel for Mac, Excel online (device agnostic), but not on Windows?**

The add-in loads fine, and there are no obvious errors. But when the function is run (on Windows) it just says:
`#BUSY` and then resolves to `#VALUE!` and stays like that.

The code also works when using the `Shared Runtime` configuration, but that requires that we make all our Javascript compatible with IE, which is definitely a possibility - but I would like to know why the regular configuration is not working.

`WISE` is the Excel function.

```
function WISE(symbol, parameter, year, quarter) {
  var param = parameter.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase();
  param = param.replace('&', 'and');
  symbol = symbol.toUpperCase();
  if (quarter == null) {
    return getAnnualData(symbol, param, year);
  } 
}

function getVal(data, param) {
  var apiResponseDataFormatted = {};
  for (var key in data) {
    apiResponseDataFormatted[key.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase()] = data[key];
  }
  var newValue = apiResponseDataFormatted[param];
  if (newValue !== 0 && !newValue) {
    newValue = 'Unavailable';
  }
  return newValue;
}

function getAnnualData(symbol, parameter, year) {
  var apiPath = requestMap[parameter];
  var response = "";
  var url = URL_API + "/" + apiPath + "/" + symbol + "?apikey=" + api_key;

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
  request.send(null);

  if (request.status === 200) {// That's HTTP for 'ok'
    response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  }else{
    return "Request Error: " + request.status + " " + url;
  }

  var apiResponseData;
  var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  if (year != null && year !== currentYear) {
    apiResponseData = response[currentYear - year - 1];
  } else {
    apiResponseData = response[0];
  }
  result = getVal(apiResponseData, parameter)

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the frustration. One of the main reason for this could be that currently on windows custom functions run in their own runtime, which is a seperate. While that runtime conserves memory, one of the limitations is it doesn't support Full CORS.

We have been recommending the use of the Shared Runtime as a way to get around this. This effectively will run the custom function in the same runtime as the taskpane, so I suspect will work for you. This also makes it easy to share state between taskpanes and functions.

Can you try that?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/share-data-and-events-between-custom-functions-and-the-task-pane-tutorial

(I realize the docs aren't super clear about this, so will follow up offline on this to get it corrected).

Comment: Hi @Keyur, Jake and I are working together on the same team - we tried placing the function script in the head tag of our task pane but the custom function still didnt work. With more research we added this to the manifest: <Runtimes> <Runtime resid="Taskpane.Url" lifetime="long" /> </Runtimes> as this is what is required to have a shared runtime and this completely broke the application and made it not load when trying to use the task pane. Do you have another other suggestion on what to do?

Comment: Hi @Keyur, really appreciate your response. How can we contact you? I'm comfortable with posting my email so that you can send me a message whilst keeping your email public. Please let me know